# do bid volumes and ask volumes represent completed trades

Tags: bid-ask

There is a number beside the current bid price and a number beside the current ask price. Do these numbers represent the volume of trades completed at the bid and ask prices or pending completion?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers that you are referring to are the bid and ask volume and they represent the size of the market at current price.

For example, the current NBBO is $10 x $11 with a size of 8 x 7.  That means that one or more people are looking to buy 800 shares at $10 and one or more people are looking to sell 700 shares at $11.

If you were to place an order to buy 500 shares at $10.25 then the quote would become $10.25 x $11 with a size of 5 x 7

Comment: “The numbers that you are referring to are the bid and ask volume...” Shouldn't that say "bid and ask size"?

Comment: "Buy volume" is used interchangeably with "ask volume" (shares offered for sale at a specific price) and conversely for  "sell volume" and "bid volume." The most common phrase used to describe this is market size as you indicated.